# Скажите плиз почему компилятор выдает ошибку в строчке "smallB [i] = big [i];" и в одном из циклов "for"?

Tags: java

```
public class Solution {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int [] big = new int [19];
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
    int length = big.length;
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        String sss = reader.readLine ();
        int enterr = Integer.parseInt (sss);
        big [i] = enterr;
    }

    int [] small = new int [9];
    for (int i = 0; i <=9; i++) {

        small [i] = big [i];
    }

    int [] smallB = new int [9];
    for(int i=10; i<=19; i--) {
        smallB [i] = big [i];
        System.out.println(smallB [i]);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: компилятор в этом коде никаких ошибок не выдает. а что вы вообще пытаетесь написать? копирование из массивов таким образом делать не рекомендуется. смотрите в сторону  Arrays.copy, а вложенные ридеры поменяйте на Scanner. кода меньше будет

Comment: Дмитрий, я пытаюсь сделать следующее: создать большой массив и два маленьких; первую половину элементов большого массива записать в один маленький, вторую половину большого массива записать во второй маленький, и у второго вывести значения на экран

Comment: тогда смотрите пункт первый - вам к Arrays.copy

Comment: Дмитрий спасибо за ответ

Comment: не за что, рад за вас, если мои комментарии помогли разобраться)